# how to download all Jenkins workspace (with .git folder) in a zip file?

Tags: jenkins

In workspace of my Jenkins, I can see all `.git` file but when I use zip link, all file is present but not SCM file.

[image]

Comment: Might have to do with Jenkins or some core plugin's  version. I am using Jenkins v2.222.4 and it works for me. Downloaded zip contains the `.git` folder

Comment: @Technext, I use 2.138.4, may be is a parameter in admin part?

Comment: If you mean to say that i configured something in admin section, then the answer is no. I just have Jenkins installed using default setting. I just went to two jobs, download the workspace zip file and noticed that both the zip files had .git folder.

Comment: problem solve in new version of Jenkins